# Which settings control the indentations of items in an enumeration?

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate, indentation

I have a bunch of `enumerate`s, which are nested quite deeply (in a document with bylaws, so I can't avoid the nesting). This results in the labels being pretty wide, with label text like "6. § 2.1.4.3", and the left edge of the label often begins to the left of the level above it. I admit that this description is rather unclear, but if you compile the MWE below you'll see the same thing happening for the bullets with respect to the text and header.

What settings should I change to move each level a little more to the right?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setenumerate[1]{label=6. \S\ 3.\arabic*.}
\setenumerate[2]{label=6. \S\ 3.2.\arabic*.}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
Some text outside the list
\begin{enumerate}
\item Here's the level above.
\begin{enumerate}
\item Here's some text on a sub-level. The text might be on several rows, so a requirement on the solution is that both the following rows and subsequent paragraphs on the same item say aligned to the first line of text, with the entire label ``outside''.

Like here.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `enumitem` package you're already using provides a `leftmargin` option. For instance

```
\setenumerate[1]{label=6. \S\ 3.\arabic*., leftmargin=5em}
```

moves the `enumerate`'s enough to the right to prevent labels from sticking in the margin on the left. It might need some fiddling to satisfy your needs, subsequent levels might require less margin and such but that is up to your own taste and can be controlled using `leftmargin` and the other options from `enumitem`.

[image: example]

As you can see, I only moved the first level to the right, the second moves with it and I wanted to prevent insanely small text.